# List in SwiftUI won't show up

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm currently writing code for a scrollable sideways calendar that displays dates horizontally.  I currently have the following code (this is a very simplified version):

```
struct ScrollableCalendar: View {

    var body: some View {
        var someArray = [["May", "10", "2020"],["May", "11", "2020"],["May", "12", "2020"]]
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                CalendarDateHorizBase(dates: someArray)
        }
        
    }

}


struct CalendarDateHorizBase: View {
    var dates: Array<Array<String>>
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ****THE LOGIC ERRROR OCCURS IN THIS LIST****
            List(dates, id: \.description) { date in
                    CalendarDate(month: date[0], day: date[1], year: date[2])
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*** CalendarDate() is another view that takes a month, day, and year (all strings) and displays them nicely.  The error is not related to CalendarDate()***

When I attempt to hardcode the elements without the List, everything displays fine.  However, when I use the List, the screen becomes completely blank.  I have no idea why.  Does anyone have any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your dates need to be a proper model as its not identifiable by List.

And also I believe you have some solid reason for using HStack, as I hope you know that list only goes vertically.

Comment: What do you mean by "a proper model?"  Like another data structure besides an array?

Comment: It will be nicely if you may update your question and explain how you make it work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the data. When you need to show a list of data in a `List`, each element of the data should be `Identifiable`. One way to achieve that is to define a structure for you data and make it `identifiable`:

```
struct DateEvent: Identifiable {
    let id: String

    let month: String
    let day: String
    let year: String

    init(rawValue: [String]) {
        month = rawValue[0]
        day = rawValue[1]
        year = rawValue[2]

        id = rawValue.joined(separator: "/")
    }
}
```

So now you can use it to build up your `List`

```
struct CalendarDateHorizBase: View {
    var dates: [[String]] // same as 'Array<Array<String>>' but more swifty style

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            List(dates.map { DateEvent(rawValue: $0) }) { date in
                CalendarDate(month: date.month, day: date.day, year: date.year)
            }
        }
    }
}
```